# How to pass a trace id between methods without passing as parameters in C#?

Tags: c#

Let’s say I have two methods

```
public async Task A()
{
   var traceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   Log($"{traceId}-Method A was called");
   await B(traceId);
}

public async Task B(string traceId)
{
   Log($"{traceId}-Method B was called");
}
```

I need to keep a log of the execution path. For this I need to pass a trace id but this clutters the code. Is there a better way to persist these types of information in C# method calls?

PS: Method A and B could be in different c# assemblies as well. This is a web application.

Comment: [`System.Diagnostics.StackTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace)?

Comment: For passing data between methods you have parameters. Depending on the environment, you could have other stores, like Request.Items for a web request, or Thread.SetData for a thread. Even a Scoped service could do the job for the current scope. Also maybe the logger could pass the "TraceId"? With a little more context about the real question behind, there might be a solution for your problem. For just tracing the excution path, you have the Stacktrace.

Comment: If this is a web application, you can put the trace ID in the principal that is put in `HttpContext.User` or in `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal`. If you are clever about it you can even propagate this trace ID to other services using context propagation behaviors in your WCF bindings. Depends how deep you want to go with it. The simplest thing, of course, is just to pass it around like a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would use a tracing/logging system that already provides this functionality, e.g., [`Activity` has an `Id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activity?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058).

But if you want to build your own, you can use [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058):

```
private static readonly AsyncLocal<string> traceId = new();

private static IDisposable SetTraceId(string id)
{
  var oldValue = traceId.Value;
  traceId.Value = id;
  return new Disposable(() => traceId.Value = oldValue);
}

public async Task A()
{
  using var _ = SetTraceId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
  Log($"{traceId.Value}-Method A was called");
  await B();
}

public async Task B()
{
  Log($"{traceId.Value}-Method B was called");
}
```

(`Disposable` is from my [Disposables library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nito.disposables/))

[My recommendations](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html) for working with `AsyncLocal<T>` are:

1. Always use immutable types for `T`. Otherwise the code can get very confusing.
2. When setting `AsyncLocal<T>.Value`, use a disposable like the code above does to reset it. Again, this makes the code less confusing.